# Javascript ternary using evaluated as result

Tags: javascript

If I combine these 2 statements:

```
x = 1+1;
y = (x<1)? x : 0;
```

to be one statement:

```
z = (1+1<1) ? 1+1 : 0;
```

Is the evaluation cached such that there would not be a performance hit?

Asked a different way, is there a way, using one variable, to use the value calculated if it meets a condition, or if not, set a value?

Comment: `x = 1+1; x = x < 1 ? x : 0` ? or do you need value of both `1+1` and the conditional setting and resetting separately later in code ?

Comment: `z` is the label of some memory space you are using to store the result of your ternary expression evaluation (here `0`). Everything else will be gone. So you're just storing one (really small) thing instead of two (really small too).

Comment: Thanks, Further clarification of question would be one statement, one variable, one calculation. Coercion operator || does not work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the evaluation cached such that there would not be a performance hit?

No, you've duplicated the code, so it will be evaluated twice. JS does not do any [common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) in general.

> Is there a way, using one variable, to use the value calculated if it meets a condition, or if not, set a value?

No, except for using a function (that internally can refer to its parameter multiple times). Assuming you meant `<= 0` when you wrote `< 1`, you could e.g. do

```
var y = Math.max(1+1, 0);
```

Comment: Good one on the often overlooked Math.max